# How could I find a value using a column other than the primary key with Diesel?

Tags: rust, rust-diesel

I have a table of users and would like to perform a search using Diesel to ensure that the username is not already taken. The only way I've found to perform queries is to use the `find()` function, which uses the primary key. Is there another function that searches using other fields, similarly to `SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = foo`?

Here's my users table:

```sql
CREATE EXTENSION IF NOT EXISTS "uuid-ossp";
CREATE TABLE users (
    user_id uuid PRIMARY KEY DEFAULT uuid_generate_v4() NOT NULL UNIQUE,
    username VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL UNIQUE,
    password VARCHAR(60) NOT NULL
);
```

And here is the Rust struct I'm using:

```rust
#[derive(Queryable, AsChangeset, Deserialize, Serialize)]
#[table_name = "users"]
pub struct User {
    pub user_id: uuid::Uuid,
    pub username: String,
    pub password: String,
}

#[derive(Insertable, Deserialize, Serialize)]
#[table_name = "users"]
pub struct InsertableUser {
    pub username: String,
    pub password: String,
}
```

Comment: You can use [`filter`](https://docs.diesel.rs/diesel/query_dsl/trait.QueryDsl.html#method.filter)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Diesel provides a general [`.filter`](https://docs.diesel.rs/1.4.x/diesel/query_dsl/trait.QueryDsl.html#method.filter) method that let's you construct arbitrary complex where clauses.
For your example query you look for something like:

```rust
users::table.filter(users::username.eq("foo"))
```